# php accessing mqsql or html accessing json or html accessing xml ? which is faster?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, xml

I have a php website where users post content and visitors add comments (sometimes no visitors add comment). After 60 days I will be renaming the .php file into .html file. Changing from php to html allows me to go for cheaper web hosting plan. Also I think the same html pages with xml or json data source will load faster than same page with php using database (I am not sure, I assume php is slower than html).

Now I am thinking the comments in these pages which had data source as mysql will have data source as xml or json. Instead of php I will use javascript to read this xml or json file and display comments. I do not want to use mongodb or anything similar. I wanted to convert php to html whereby retaining the ability to add comments. I do not want to use third party comments plugin such as facebook javascript api.

1) How do I do it ? any suggestion?
2) Which is faster for data retrieval:
     a) html accessing xml datasource
     b) html accessing json datasource
    c) php accessing mysql database. Note: data is 0 to 100kb max, server configuration and everything else is constant. Also I understand mqsql helps me manage data effectively, but since I am only having few tables for all my comments, i am not worried about overhead or difficulties in data management. I need speed and performance.

Comment: It's **JSON**, not jason *(or ask Jason if he's okay about HTML "accessing him")*

Comment: A question you could ask yourself would be: **do I need a *static* or *dynamic* website ?**

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. HTML and PHP do very different things. You cannot "convert" one to the other. You will always need HTML on the web. Whether you *also* need a server-side language like PHP depends on what you want to do. And yes, with what you want to do, you *need* a server-side language. Performance has little to do with anything; you can write a server-side program which processes dynamic requests *very very fast*, in the best case making it almost indistinguishable from a static web server.

Comment: And web hosting is so incredibly cheap these days that you surely can find a host you can afford. It's such a commodity that PHP processing is thrown in virtually for free and you'll have a hard time locating a host that hosts static sites significantly cheaper than one hosting PHP. Perhaps write the entire thing "serverless" (e.g. AWS Lambda), and you'll pay next to nothing for a lightly visited site.

Comment: 1) json auto corrected to Jason, 2) I am thinking dynamic content using javascript with the ability to read from xml or json instead of php reading mysql database.

Comment: If all you want to do is *reading*… sure. But I guess you also want to *write* new comments, no?

Comment: yes. I wanted to write new comment. I will do that with the same html file with form having action to .php file. This php file will update the xml or json file on my server. I wanted to know if php read mqsql is faster or php read xml or php read json. what do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do it ?

You can't. You need server-side code to store data on the server. This is still true even if you store it in an inefficient system (like a JSON file instead of a real database).

> Also I think the same html pages with xml or jason data source will load faster … Which is faster for data retrieval

This is a classic case of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Don't select random parts of your system and try to squeeze microseconds of performances out of them. It is pointless, painful, and expensive. Optimize the things which are actually slow.

Comment: I can. My form will have post to .php file. my current file is still .html. The form action is .php, And I still need server-side code, you are correct. I will use .php file to add comment into json or xml. when I read I will use html via javascript to read content from xml or json. So you think json is faster than xml ?

Comment: @PoornendulalVenugopalan — I think getting rid of the database is a pointless waste of time.

Comment: @PoornendulalVenugopalan —"My form will have post to .php file." — That prevents your goal of moving to a cheaper hosting plan.

Comment: why is getting rid of database pointless ?

Comment: @PoornendulalVenugopalan — Because you are doing a bunch of work to remove a tool designed to solve your problem and replace it with a homebrewed version which will probably be less efficient and will certainly lack features such as defences against simultaneous write conflicts.

Comment: yeah. I get your point.